# UILabel with Tap Gesture Recognizer not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have designed a `UICollectionViewCell` using `XIB` and in that custom cell I have an `UILabel` whose user interaction I have enabled.

In my `viewcontroller` when I am designing the `cell`, Here is my code.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *buyNowTapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buyNowClicked:)];
buyNowTapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1.0;
cell.buy.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.buy.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[cell.buy addGestureRecognizer:buyNowTapped];

-(void)buyNowClicked : (id)sender
{
  UIButton *button;
  UILabel *label;
  if([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
  {
      button = (UIButton *)sender;
      [self buyService:button.tag];
  }
  else if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
  {
    label = (UILabel *)sender;
    [self buyService:label.tag];
  }
}
```

But the added tap gesture does not work.

Comment: show `buyNowClicked` function ..

Comment: Check `buy` label view hierarchy, see other views not blocking its `userInteraction`

Comment: I have added the description

Comment: enable userInteraction

Comment: so the issue is that buyNowClicked is never called, isn't it? can you put an NSLog in it in order to be sure it is never called?

Comment: No it is not and now I get the issue the problem is that the cell tap gesture overrides the tap gesture on label

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to rework your design and change the `UILabel` to an `UIButton`, because `UIButton` simply handles tap recognition, and also you do not have any issue of tap forwarded also to the `UICollectionView` (`didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` will be called indeed).

So, change the label with a button and set `buyNowClicked:` method at `TouchUpInside` event on it.

**UPDATE:** If you can't remove the UILabel for any reason, then put a `UIButton` under the `UILabel` (with same `frame` and eventually `NSConstraints`) and move `buyNowClicked:` method at `TouchUpInside` event on the button and then you win easily

Comment: I know that is better but I have certain design constraint to tae it this way

Comment: @AvinashSharma, ok, then put a UIButton under the UILabel (with same frame and eventually constraints) and move buyNowClicked: method at TouchUpInside event on the button and then you win easily :)

Comment: yeah that seems the easiest way

Answer (score 1):

create custome cell with tag property and use

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row);
}
```

**Note:** added TapGestureRecognizer somewhere and it prevents selecton of cell `didselectitematindexpath`

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to add this code into the Your Custom `UICollectionViewCell` class.
2. Then create a delegate which will respond to the tap.
3. Assign that delegate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of Collection View.

let me know if you need detailed explanation.

Edit 1: Code:

**MyCell.swift:**

```
import UIKit

protocol MyCellDelegate {
    func lblNameTapped(cell: MyCell)
}

class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var lblName: UILabel!
    var lblNameTapRec:UITapGestureRecognizer!
    var delegate: MyCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        lblNameTapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyCell.lblNameTapped(_:)))
        lblName.userInteractionEnabled = true
        lblName.addGestureRecognizer(lblNameTapRec)
    }

    func lblNameTapped(sender: AnyObject){
        delegate?.lblNameTapped(self)
    }

}
```

**ViewController.Swift:**

```
import UIKit

class WallOfPraizeVC: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,MyCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    //DelegateMethod
    func lblNameTapped(cell: MyCell) {
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        print(indexPath!.row)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: But then how will I know the label tag

Comment: You want to open some View Controller when user presses on Label?

Comment: I need to call a service on tap which needs to know the cell index that was tapped

Comment: Have you implemented Gesture recognizer and Custom Delegates in Table before?

Comment: Give me few moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
-(void)buyNowClicked:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
    NSLog(@"buyNowClicked here");
    [self buyService:tap.view.tag];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for tap gesture: -

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *buyNowTapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buyNowClicked:)];
    buyNowTapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1.0;
    cell.buy.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.buy.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [cell.buy addGestureRecognizer:buyNowTapped];


    Try this :

    -(void)buyNowClicked : :(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
    {

        UIView *view = [recognizer view];

        NSLog(@"tag %ld",(long)view.tag);

      UIButton *button;
      UILabel *label;

      if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
      {
          button = (UIButton *)sender;
          [self buyService:button.tag];
      }
      else if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
      {
        label = (UILabel *)sender;
        [self buyService:label.tag];
      }
    }
```