# How to add only one tapGesture to image in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `tableView` with custom cells. I have in one cell a `imageView`. I want add to this `imageView` one `tapGesture` for load a function then I click the `imageView`.  So I have this code into `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.image setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell.image addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

and

```
-(void)tapDetected:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"single Tap on imageview");
}
```

My problem is that when I scroll the table view this tap is added multiple times and changes into `imageView` then first click changes.

How can I change add only one time the `tapGesture` to all cells?

Comment: Do you want either the same tap gesture for all images or skip if the imageview already containts the tap gesture?

Comment: I want add the same gesture for all images in the rows but ONLY ONE TIME. My functions do it, but constantly when I scroll the table. I only want add this first time because if is adding constantly the values changes by my tap function...

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't remove any existing tap recognizer first, then add it?

Comment: Check `if cell.image.gestureRecognizers.count > 0`. If it is, DO NOT add the gesture recognizer to the image because one already exists.

Comment: Check this answer: [UIlabel tap gesture recognizer not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163577/uilabel-tap-gesture-recognizer-not-working/39163664#answer-39163664). Just use `UIImageView` instead of `UILabel` and `UITableView` instead of `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a custom cell you can a function like this:

```
-(void) addTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapGesture {
    if (self.tapGesture == nil) {
        [self.image setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self.image addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

        self.tapGesture = tapGesture
    }
}
```

in this way you are sure to set the tapGesture just once per cell.

*Let me know if this can fix your problem*

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

Right now, you are adding a new TapGestureRecognizer every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, which is every time a cell is about to appear on the screen!

**Solution 1: Keep the Old Gesture Recognizer**

You can also just check if a cell already contains a gesture recognizer and not add a new one if it does. This will ensure that only one TapGestureRecognizer is applied to each cell:

```
// Check if the cell already contains a gesture recognizer
//  if not, add one! 
if (cell.gestureRecognizers.count == 0) {
    // Now add the tap gesture recognizer and it will be the only one
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell.image setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.image addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}
```

> Note: You should probably check and make sure the cell contains
>   exactly the gesture recognizer that you desire- you may want to add
>   more gesture recognizers to your cells and then you'll have to make
>   sure it contains the right one!

**Solution 2: Remove Gesture Recognizers**

Remove all gesture recognizers from the cell before adding the TapGestureRecognizer. This will ensure that only one TapGestureRecognizer is applied to each cell:

```
// Removes all gesture recognizers in the cell
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in cell.gestureRecognizers) {
    [cell removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

// Now add the tap gesture recognizer and it will be the only one
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.image setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell.image addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Answer (score 0):

just in you custom cell,do this :(i use swift as example)

```
class YourCell:UITableViewCell{
//add a variable to track has added a tapgesture to image view
var isAddedTapGesture = false
......
}
```

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if(cell.isAddedTapGesture == false){
//add the tap gesture to your image
cell.cell.isAddedTapGesture = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom cell header, create a property like

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture;

Add Getter method for the gesture.

```
- (UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapGesture{
    if (!_tapGesture) {
        _tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
    }

    return _tapGesture;
}
```

and inside the awakeFomNib function, Remove and re - add the gesture for the image view like the below.

```
[self.image removeGestureRecognizer:self.tapGesture];
[self.image addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGesture];
```

Hope this will be helpfull.