# How can I add LongPress Gesture for a label in UICollectionViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to add ***LongPress*** gesture to label in a cell of *`UICollectionView`* but it doesn't work.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
private lazy var longpressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = {
        let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longpressGestureRecognizer))
        return gesture
    }()


@objc private func longpressGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    print("here")
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {
        cell.label.addGestureRecognizer(longpressGesture)
    }
}
```

And ***CustomCell***:

```
class CalendarSlotCell: UICollectionViewCell {
   let label: UILabel = {
       let lb = UILabel()
       lb.text = "Pressme"
       return lb
   }()
}
```

Nothing happens when I press the label.

**Note**: I can add **LongPress** gesture for cell like below and it worked but what I want to do is add LongPress gesture to ***label in cell*** not ***just for cell***.

Add LongPress gesture for cell, in viewDidLoad function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}
```

**Edit**

It not like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163577/uilabel-with-tap-gesture-recognizer-not-working) because when i replace **UILabel** with **UIImageView** or anything else it does not work too.

In addition, if my problem is *UILabel with Tap Gesture Recognizer not working* i can resolve it like this:

```
var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))

 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        return cell
    }
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UILabel with Tap Gesture Recognizer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163577/uilabel-with-tap-gesture-recognizer-not-working)

Comment: Obviously nothing get happened when you click first time because you are adding gesture recognizer in didSelect method. Instead add gesture in cellForRow method

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding it to a label i will suggest you to have a small view inside the cell that view will contain the label.
Apply long press gesture to that label.

Also heres a small article for that,

https://medium.com/@sdrzn/adding-gesture-recognizers-with-closures-instead-of-selectors-9fb3e09a8f0b